# Purview Collection - Move Entities To Collection

Tags: azure, azure-purview

How can we move purview entities between collections using API's?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this Azure Purview REST API documentation which has description with sample: [Collection - Move Entities To Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/collection/move-entities-to-collection)

Moving existing entities to a target collection:

> POST {Endpoint}/catalog/api/collections/{collection}/entity/moveHere?api-version=2021-05-01-preview

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve this by following the instruction in below link--> https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/all/python.html

Comment: https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-purview-catalog/1.0.0b2/index.html